# auto changes meaning in C++11; please remove it what does this mean?

Tags: c++, c++11, timestamp, milliseconds

I am running my below code which checks whether `data_timestamp` is more than two weeks old or not. If it is two weeks old, then print hello otherwise prints world.

I am a Java developer, recently started working with C++. Learned few things over internet so I am using it here in this program.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // this has to be uint64_t bcoz of old code
    uint64_t data_timestamp = 1406066507000; 

    const auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto twoWeeks = std::chrono::hours(24 * 14);
    auto lastTwoWeeks = now - twoWeeks;

    auto millis = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(lastTwoWeeks.time_since_epoch()).count();

    std::cout << "Time stamp in milliseconds since UNIX epoch start: "<< millis << std::endl;

    if (data_timestamp < millis) { 
        std::cout << "Hello"; 
    } else { 
        std::cout << "World"; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I will be running this code on Ubuntu 12.04. When I am compiling it while running `make install`, it is giving me this exception -

```
warning: âautoâ changes meaning in C++11; please remove it [-Wc++0x-compat]
error: ânowâ does not name a type
warning: âautoâ changes meaning in C++11; please remove it [-Wc++0x-compat]
âtwoWeeksâ does not name a type
warning: âautoâ changes meaning in C++11; please remove it [-Wc++0x-compat]
error: âlastTwoWeeksâ does not name a type
warning: âautoâ changes meaning in C++11; please remove it [-Wc++0x-compat]
error: âmillisâ does not name a type
error: âmillisâ was not declared in this scope
```

May be, I am not having `C++11`. This is a simple program which I made but the core logic of this program I am using it in a big C++ project so it looks like, I cannot port everything to C++11 to make this work. Is there any other way by which I can write this code which does not use C++11?

**Update:-**

This is the way I am getting current timestamp in milliseconds in that big project at some part of the code -

```
struct timeval tp;
gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);
uint64_t current_ms = tp.tv_sec * 1000 + tp.tv_usec / 1000; //get current timestamp in milliseconds
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The new meaning of `auto` (deduce the type) was introduced in C++11. Compile your code with the flag `-std=c++11`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Actually the core logic of this program I am using it in big project which is not C++11 portable I guess so is there any way of rewriting this so that I don't need to use C++11 at all? I have updated the question with the way I am calculating current timestamp in milliseconds as of now. May be from that it can give you any idea how do I rewrite?

Comment: @user2809564 If you use the `chrono` header at all then you *must* compile with C++11 mode turned on. If you absolutely cannot use C++11 then you'll have to find an alternative. (And of course don't use `auto`.)

Comment: Yes I guess, I cannot use C++11 which means I need to find an alternative for now. Can you think of any? I was not sure on this C++11. I thought it would get compiled everywhere. This is what java developer has to learn I guess while working with C++. :)

Comment: @user2809564 Consider using Boost.Chrono. That's the library that C++11 `std::chrono` is based on.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I do have Boost include headers in my project so I can definitely use it for sure. Can you provide an example if possible how would I do it using Boost here?

Comment: @user2809564 See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/chrono/users_guide.html#chrono.users_guide.examples

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58835/discussion-between-user2809564-and-brian).

Comment: I haven't looked at the chat, so maybe this has already been discussed, but all you should have to do is use types from a different namespace (`boost` rather than `std`).